# Stack layout differently on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to stack three div's differently based on desktop, mobile and tablet with out having to duplicate the div's.
It should look like this
[image]

Is this possible with pure css?
A javascript answer will be fine if there is no way to do this with css alone.
Here is a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19086/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 sidebar-block">
    <div class="block" style="background-color:red;"></div>
  </div>
<div class="col-lg-6  col-sm-8 col-xs-12 ">
  <div class="block" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <div class="block" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you did it already... I am confused...

Comment: Why don't try a [grid builder](http://shoelace.io)?

Comment: @Neal Mine doesn't work

Comment: @Neal - the desired layout has blue first on mobile.

Comment: ahhh did not see that @Skelly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think "mobile first", use `col-*-push`/`col-*-pull` classes like this..

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4 col-xs-12 ">
            <div class="block" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-pull-6 col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-8 col-xs-12 sidebar-block">
            <div class="block" style="background-color:red;"></div>
       </div>    
       <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
            <div class="block" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
       </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/N8wCdrlkK3

Comment: Nice, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks